# JTable only shows the right border of the table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` and I want to make a tic tac toe themed table. I have managed to get rid of three borders without really knowing how...

Here's my code:

```
public class Table extends JPanel {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        JTable table = new JTable(3, 3);

        table.setBounds(90, 20, 200, 200);
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            table.setRowHeight(i, 67);        

        }
        table.setBackground(Color.black);
        table.setGridColor(Color.white);
        table.setForeground(Color.white);

        // content pane so I can set the background
        jFrame.getContentPane().add(table);
        jFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        jFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        jFrame.setLayout(null);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

I also have some stuff that initializes the table more like setting values but I don't think that will matter but I can add it if you want. So how could I get the right border of the table to disappear too?

*When I compile this code, the top, left and bottom borders are not visible*

Answer (score 1):

You can use`setBorder` method with a `LineBorder` in order to fill it:

```
table.setGridColor(Color.white);
table.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(table.getGridColor()));
```

By the way, `setLayout(null)` and `setBounds` is a bad practice that is going to give you hard time in the future (plus it is not user-friendly, since you cannot resize your frame and won't work in different screen sizes). Try to [use LayoutManagers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and let them do the work for you.

Also, take a look at [initial threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). All swing applications should run on their own thread and not in the main thread.